# git shortlog for facebook application shows unknown authors

Tags: facebook, git, heroku

I'm currently developing a facebook application hosted on heroku and was curious to know the number of git commits I did so far.`Note:I am the only one doing the project.`
I used the following command

> git shortlog -s -n

Please find below the result, the first one is obviously me.
Why does it display many unknown authors who I have never even heard of, how is that even possible ?
Did anyone else see this or am I the only one having this situtaion ? 
Is it possible that by default all fb apps hosted on heroku have these commit figures ?

[image]

If at all this is a possible duplicate, kindly point me towards it.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say you've used the Heroku Facebook application template - several of those names I recognise as Heroku workers so their history remains in the git repo.

UPDATE: Yep, check the commits of this repo https://github.com/heroku/facebook-template-php/commits/master which is probably what you're based off.